# Modal popup in Classic ASP?

Tags: ajax, asp-classic, modalpopups

I write in .NET and in classic ASP. 
I want to create a modal popup in ASP, like in .NET how the parent page can be disabled and turned a different color. 
Is this possible in ASP? 
Or is there no easy solution to get this done? 
If possible...how?

Answer (score 3):

You're going to use Javascript to make something like that, I'd recommend you [use jQuery](http://www.jquery.com). There is a lot of prebuilt libraries to help you do that.

For the modal box, you might start with [the jQuery Dialog](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog).

Comment: So far this is the one i like best. +1. I haven't mastered it yet though.

Comment: Great! You're going to find a lot of options when it comes to Javascript modal/dialog boxes, but jQuery has an huge community of developers working to create add-ons and improve the code -- in general, you're going to find a lot more use from jQuery than just the dialog box

Answer (score 2):

Just use a javascript library to do this.  [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is a popular choice and there a number of plugins to do this.

- [jqModal](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/#examples)
- [thickbox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course, but if you are writing the Javascript yourself, you can just create a hidden DIV tag that has the same exact page rendered, but with a 15% gray - transparent .gif file that sits on top of what is displayed. Then you change that DIV tag to visable when the Modal dialog is launched, and change it back when it's closed. Simple.

Answer (score 1):

There are some great JS libraries out there that can help you.
I like jQuery and YUI for their ease of use.

Try this link and look around at some of their Panel offerings.. all of which have a Modal setting that will grey out the background.

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/container/panel-loading.html

Good Luck~

Answer (score 0):

" how the parent page can be disabled and turned a different color"

You can use the ibox javascript, I have used it with good results.

http://www.ibegin.com/labs/ibox/

Comment: Eric, it's in the samples, you must include ibox/ibox.js in your asp file.

Answer (score 0):

I'd put a vote in for stickywin from the clientcide site. Its all Mootools bases and very sweet to use.